# Line integral over a vector field using a potential function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

Let $X(t)=\left ( \pi\cos t, t, e^{\sin t} \right ), 0\leq t\leq \pi $.
And let $\textbf{F}(x,y,z)=\left ( 2xy+\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, x^2+ze^{yz}+\frac x{x^2+y^2}, ye^{yz} \right )$ be a vector field.

I want to calculate $\int _X\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{s}$.

First, I found that $\varphi (x,y,z)=x^2y+e^{yz}+\arctan \frac yx$ is a potential function of $\textbf{F}$.
So I had $\int _X\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{s}=\int _Xgrad\varphi \cdot d\textbf{s}=\int_{0}^{\pi }grad\varphi (X(t))\cdot X'(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac d{dt}\left ( \varphi (X(t)) \right )dt=\varphi (X(\pi ))-\varphi (X(0))$.

But I figured out that $\varphi$ is not a potential function of $\textbf{F}$ since $\varphi$ is not differentiable at which $x=0$. I know that if $X$ does not pass through $x=0$, then there is no problem with above calculation. However, the given $X$ passes through $(0,\frac{\pi}2,e)$. Calculation by definition of line intgral is too hard for me. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with differentiability unless both $x$ and $y$ are $0$, which cannot happen for your curve where $x(t)=\pi\cos t$ and $y(t)=t$. If $y$ is $0$, then $t=0$, in which case $x=x(0)\ne 0$. So I think everything's okay.

Comment: Is φ differentiable at (0,π/2,e)?

Comment: @user112018: The integral of F is well behaved over [0,\pi] because F is continuous over the entire curve. So, you can break the integral into intervals [0,\pi/2-\delta] [\pi/2+\delta,\pi] and then let \delta tend downward to 0. Those integrals can be directly evaluated using your method, and the limits are known to exist ahead of time because of the continuity of F(X(t)) along the entire path and the smoothness of X.

Answer (score 2):

Your path is $\textbf{r}=(\pi \cos t,t,e^{\sin t})\space(t\in[0,\pi])$. Hence $\textbf{dr}=(-\pi \sin t,1,e^{\sin t}\cos t)dt$. Along the path $\textbf{F}$ is 
$$\left(2\pi t\cos t-{t\over \pi^2\cos ^2t+t^2},\pi^2\cos ^2t+e^{\sin t+te^{\sin t}}+{\pi \cos t\over \pi^2\cos ^2t+t^2},te^{te^{\sin t}}\right)$$
And **F$\cdot$dr**/dt is $$-\pi^2 t\sin 2t+{\pi t\sin t\over \pi^2\cos ^2t+t^2}+\pi^2\cos ^2t+e^{\sin t+te^{\sin t}}+{\pi \cos t\over \pi^2\cos ^2t+t^2}+\cos t.te^{te^{\sin t}+\sin t}$$
Over $[0,\pi]$ integrals of both $1$st and $3$rd terms evaluate to ${\pi^3\over 2}$. Now notice that $${de^{te^{\sin t}}\over dt}=e^{te^{\sin t}+\sin t}{\left(1+t\cos t\right)}=\text{integrand for the 4th term+last term }$$  As a result contribution of those terms in the integral is $e^{\pi}-1$.
Anti-derivative of the sum of the $2$nd and $5$-th term is
$$\pi \int{t\sin t+\cos t\over \pi^2\cos ^2t+t^2}dt=\pi \int{t\sec t.\tan  t+\sec t\over \pi^2+t^2\sec ^2t}dt=\pi \int{{d(t\sec t)\over dt}\over  \pi^2+t^2\sec ^2t}dt=\pi \int{1\over\pi^2+u^2}du=\tan  ^{-1}{u\over \pi}+C=\tan  ^{-1}{t\sec t\over \pi}+C$$

So contribution of those terms evaluates to $\tan  ^{-1}(\sec \pi)={3\pi \over 4}.$
So the final line integral
is$${\pi^3}+{3\pi \over 4}+e^{\pi}-1$$
Same as what your potential function gives.....